# What would be the procedures to install Gnome 3.35.90 (3.36 beta) on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-gnome

#### Background

I've been using Ubuntu and Gnome for some time now but I've never really gotten into installing the betas. Recently, when 3.35.90 was released, I was really intrigued to just try it out. However, I couldn't find any tutorials explaining the procedure.

---

#### Question

What are the actual procedures to install the beta releases of gnome on Ubuntu 19.10 and, in particular, the latest 3.36 beta?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072096/how-to-install-gnoOme-3-29-92-or-3-30-in-ubuntu-18-04 adjust the version numbers as you need them.

Comment: Sitenote: it would be less risky to use 20.04 If needed use virtualbox, install 20.04 in there.

Comment: Thank you, but that seems like a very extensive method. Given how many YouTubers and others are installing the beta I figured there would be an easier way :/ If that's the step I need to take I'll probably wait until the real release.... Know of any simpler way?